# maven, maven-glassfish-plugin, domain creation

Tags: maven, glassfish

I try to create domain by maven

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
        <user>${glassfish.username}</user>
        <adminPassword>${glassfish.password}</adminPassword>
        <autoCreate>true</autoCreate>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <echo>true</echo>
        <terse>true</terse>
        <domain>
            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
            <adminPort>4048</adminPort>
            <httpPort>4080</httpPort>
            <httpsPort>4043</httpsPort>
            <iiopPort>4037</iiopPort>
            <reuse>false</reuse>
        </domain>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
            </component>
        </components>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

domain created but not started

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building EventLogger
[INFO]    task-segment: [org.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [glassfish:deploy {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Domain event-logger isn't started. Starting it for you.
[INFO] Domain event-logger does not exist. Creating it for you.
[INFO] CLI031 Warning: Option "profile" is obsolete and will be ignored.
[INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile /tmp/mgfp1661748332213879832.tmp --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=true create-domain --adminport 4048 --profile developer --domaindir /home/makaka/glassfish3/glassfish/domains --instanceport 4080 --savemasterpassword=false --usemasterpassword=false --domainproperties http.ssl.port=4043:orb.listener.port=4037 --savelogin=false --nopassword=false --checkports=true event-logger
[INFO] The AS_ADMIN_ADMINPASSWORD option in the password file is deprecated.
[INFO] Use AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD instead.
[INFO] Distinguished Name of the self-signed X.509 Server Certificate is:
[INFO] [CN=ubuntu,OU=GlassFish,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Santa Clara,ST=California,C=US]
[INFO] Distinguished Name of the self-signed X.509 Server Certificate is:
[INFO] [CN=ubuntu-instance,OU=GlassFish,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Santa Clara,ST=California,C=US]
[INFO] No domain initializers found, bypassing customization step
[INFO] Domain event-logger created.
[INFO] Domain event-logger admin port is 4048.
[INFO] Domain event-logger admin user is "admin".
[INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile /tmp/mgfp1661748332213879832.tmp --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=true start-domain --verbose=false --upgrade=false --debug=true --_dry-run=false --domaindir /home/makaka/glassfish3/glassfish/domains event-logger
[ERROR] The Master Password is required to start the domain.  No console, no prompting possible.  You should either create the domain with --savemasterpassword=true or provide a password file with the --passwordfile option.
[ERROR] Unable to start domain "event-logger".
[ERROR] For more detail on what might be causing the problem try running maven with the --debug option
[ERROR] or setting the maven-glassfish-plugin "echo" property to "true".
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to start domain "event-logger".
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 27 21:03:48 MSK 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/74M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Right after creation I can manually start domain, but can't log in to admin panel - invalid password.

If after creation I manually reset the password - Maven still can't start domain. But I can manually start domain from command line and then login to admin panel...

I tried to use passwordFile instead of adminPassword. Nothing changed... Content of that file (I created it manually):

```
AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD myPass
AS_ADMIN_USERPASSWORD myPass
AS_ADMIN_ALIASPASSWORD myPass
```

Also I wonder why asadmin needs master password - it's not for autentification [master pass description](https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/what_is_a_glassfish_master)

Any ideas what's wrong?

P.S. I use ubunutu 12.10, glassfish 3.1.2.2, used developer profile to install glassfish

Answer (score 1):

I had a wrong password file. It should contain

```
AS_MASTER_PASSWORD=myPass1
AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=myPass2
AS_ADMIN_USERPASSWORD=myPass3
```